# How do I store the data in disk directly in kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, tcp, block-device

I capture the TCP packet in function of `netif_receive_skb` , I want to  store the playload of TCP packet.
we can't read/write the file in kernel module, so store in disk directly maybe a  way?
      This is a good way, or other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You may find that approaching your requirements from a different angle satisfies your need.

`iptables` has a `-j NFQUEUE` option (see `man iptables`) that allows you to queue selected packets for userspace. In your userspace program it would be trivial to write the packets to disk.

See https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/ for some really interesting details, which I should point out I've only skimmed.